# Puppet - No Listener on 8140: Job for puppetserver.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Tags: ubuntu, services, puppet

I have a Puppet setup that was working at one point in time. Now when I run a netstat -lnp I do not see the Puppet Server listening on 8140.

In troubleshooting I've tried to manually start the puppet service with:

```
sudo service puppetserver.service start
```

However, this gets the following error:

```
Job for puppetserver.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status puppetserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status puppetserver.service yeilds:

```
puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-05-06 13:05:42 UTC; 2min 14s ago
  Process: 14338 ExecStart=/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/bin/puppetserver start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13555 (java)
    Tasks: 35 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           └─13555 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djruby.logger.class=com.puppetlabs.jruby_utils.jruby.Slf4jLogger -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar:/opt/puppetlabs
```

Which to me seems to suggest that maybe its working / running? I'm still not sure why I'm not seeing a listener with netstat.

In case someone wonders journalctl -xe does not have anything associated with Puppet in it.

None of the logs within /var/log/puppetlabs have a timestamp from this year, which seems REALLY weird to me if the server is actually running properly. (I validated the system date is set properly)

netstat output is:

```
root@box:/var/log/puppetlabs# netstat -lnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15703/systemd-resol
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1029/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25324           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2418/ruby
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:64652           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1029/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1029/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::64652                :::*                    LISTEN      1029/sshd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           15703/systemd-resol
udp        0      0 172.26.10.238:68        0.0.0.0:*                           15684/systemd-netwo
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25224         0.0.0.0:*                           2418/ruby
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           15684/systemd-netwo
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20448    940/syslog-ng        /var/lib/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.ctl
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     13850    1/systemd            /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51512    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51516    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51517    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51518    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51519    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     51520    7986/systemd         /run/user/1001/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21778    1072/omiengine       /var/opt/omi/run/omiserver.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18812    1/systemd            /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     180883   1/systemd            /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     180886   1/systemd            /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18867    1/systemd            /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18892    1/systemd            /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18895    1/systemd            /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21772    1069/omiserver       /etc/opt/omi/conf/sockets/omi_Hyxssiwgw
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18894    1/systemd            @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     107719   1/systemd            /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13848    1/systemd            /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13856    1/systemd            /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13864    1/systemd            /run/systemd/journal/stdout
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further and hopefully fix it?

I don't imagine this should matter, but this is running on Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Downvotes are a lot more useful if you state why you think the question is bad. I'm happy to update / fix this to clarify.

Comment: I haven't voted, but a couple suggestions: (1) show the output of the `netstat`, perhaps grepping for the port. (2) did you really run `sudo service ...` and not `sudo service ... start`? (3) Is it possible that something else has taken port 8140 and the service started anyway?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks, I fixed the typo and added the netstat output.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to troubleshoot this utilizing:

```
sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppetserver foreground &
```

This allowed me to see any of the errors or issues that were happening when Puppet was starting up. As it turns out there weren't any errors at first (hence the confusion). However, when enough of the agents checked in at the same time the system was running out-of-memory and everything was crashing. I do not know why this wasn't in the logs anywhere.

The solution was to move everything to a VM with more memory. Once this was done the application responded faster and came up fully and was listening on all the ports / working properly.

Hopefully this helps someone else that stumbles across this post.